# Setting another field in access when the current field is changed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an irritating problem.  When I am in a field in Access, and if it is changed, I want to set another field to null.  So, I have the following code blocks in the Dirty, and Exit events are hit.  The problem is that it clears the other field, then "selects all" of the current field, instead of exiting.  If I try to exit again, then it works, but not that first time.

```
Private Sub EWId_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
' Clear out the EID when this is changed.
  DirtyEWID = True
End Sub

Private Sub EWId_Enter()
  DirtyEWID = False
End Sub

Private Sub EWId_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
  If (DirtyEWID = True) Then
    Me![txtEID] = ""
    DirtyEWID = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand the issue, but maybe you can slide a Me.txtEID.SetFocus in there?  This way it won't highlight anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by moving the change to the "after update" event.

Thanks!